Flutter: setting macos deployment version in XCode doesn't work
I've added the image_editor plugin to my Flutter project. When I debug my app on macOS I get the following error when the build tries to install the Podfile:
Error: The plugin "image_editor_common" requires a higher minimum macOS deployment
version than your application is targeting.
To build, increase your application's deployment target to at least 10.15 as described
at https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/macos

I've followed the linked instructions. I opened macos/Runner.xcworkspace in XCode, clicked on the project named "Runner", then clicked on the "Runner" target, and then the "General" tab. There's a "Minimum Deployments" section on that tab, I changed it from 10.14 to 10.15. But when I re-ran my app I got the same error. After poking around I found a "macOS Deployment Target" setting in the Project | Info page that was still set to 10.14, and changed that as well. But the build still gives me the same "requires a minimum macOS deployment version" error.
I'm new to macOS and Flutter development, what am I missing?

I found the solution. In addition to setting minimum deployment target in the Runner project and target in XCode, I also needed to manually change the deployment target version in the first line of macos/Podfile:
platform :osx, '10.15'

